# File remaining locked in Windows after Java File.canWrite() returning true and all close() methods called

Tags: java, windows, file-io, jvm, file-locking

I'm using a `WatchService` to check for the addition of a file to a directory. A listener then  gets an input stream from the file in the form of a ByteBuffer wrapped in a custom class (See below).

The issue is that despite calling `close()` on every relevant object (and a few more too), and checking that the file is not locked with `File.canWrite()` (which returns true), Windows still complains that the file is locked by the JVM when I try to move it.

I have scoured the code for anything which might be locking the file, but since `canWrite()` is returning true I'm not sure what else I can do. Does anyone have any ideas?

The skeleton of the custom class is as follows. I realise this may not be the best implementation but I don't know whether it's causing the issue either.

```
private static class ByteBufferBackedInputStream extends InputStream {

    private final ByteBuffer  buf;
    private final FileChannel channel;

    public ByteBufferBackedInputStream(FileInputStream fs) throws IOException {

        this.channel = fs.getChannel();
        this.buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());

        fs.close();
    }

    //... all required methods implemented, including close() method

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit** Following on from the first comments, I am using `buf.close()` and this isn't helping. I've also stepped through the whole process and no exceptions are being thrown - just to be sure I am using `finally` blocks.

I have a feeling this may somehow be to do my implementation of the `WatchService` but it doesn't explicitly use any IO methods, just a producer and consumer `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

**Edit 2** As Andreas suggested in the comments below, using a standard read()/write() operation worked and the file was not locked. Ultimately, the use of a buffer was legacy code (possibly for optimisation when dealing with potentially large files) so can be safely changed for now.

None the less, the question still remains technically unanswered so I'll leave it open for now. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Not sure if this will help.... but you can try buf.clear() to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: did you try debugging,there might be a case when there an exception and your file is not closed

Comment: Thanks for the responses. `buf.clear()` is in the `close()` method and this hasn't helped. I've also debugged and caught all possible exceptions with `close()` methods in `finally` blocks and this hasn't resolved the problem either.

Comment: Did you try to replace the memory mapping with normal read()/write() - operations from the stream? There are some comments in the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map) that sound strange - like, that closing the channel has no impact on the validity of the mapping. But, on Windows, at some point, the runtime needs to call the closeHandle() Windows API function on the memory mapping object ... BTW: `File.canWrite()` only checks if the file is there and if the permissions would allow to write to the file. It does not check for locks.